# Flutter Widgets alignment is not responsive

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I recently learnt flutter and this is my first app. It basically shows off some Cricket score details. This works on mobile phones just fine but the alignments goes off when opened on tablets. What am I doing wrong here? I positioned and sized the widgets previewing on my phone m0stly.

Comment: Well looking at the code, you're using a lot of fixed sizes, this might not even work correctly on small screen displays. Try reading about `Flexible` and `Expanded`. As well as Flex derivatives like `Row` and `Column`

Comment: Yes. Flexible did the work. Thanks

Comment: Great! :D Maybe edit the question and provide your own solution or answer it yourself, so it acts like a wiki for future searches by people! :)

Comment: Id love to @ishaan but for now Im gonna remove the question. Id probably post again after releasing the app. :)